# For Sikuli observations, do I need to set the scan rate per region being observed

Tags: automation, sikuli, sikuli-script

I know that when using the Sikuli observer function, you can set a scan rate for the observation:

```
Settings.ObserveScanRate = (number of observes per second)
```

The example given in the sikuli documentation only has one observation acting on the default region (which is the screen). My question is do I need to apply the scan rate per region or does defining the `ObserveScanRate` apply to all observations regardless of region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a general setting in Sikuli and will be used globally, for any region. You can see this and all the available settings in the Settings class here [sikuli.basics.settings](http://doc.sikuli.org/javadoc/org/sikuli/script/Settings.html#ObserveScanRate).